# Sending multiple parameters to POST method in .net:

Tags: rest

I'm struggling to use POST method for RESTful services. My requirement is some parameters I need to append (not in the URL) and 2 parameters I need to read from file. The service is written in Java.

```
string url= "http://srfmdpimd2:18109/1010-SF-TNTIN/Configurator/rest/importConfiguration/"

HttpWebRequest request = (HttpWebRequest)WebRequest.Create(url);
FileStream file = new FileStream(@"TestSCDS.properties", FileMode.Open);
Byte[] bytes = new Byte[file.Length];
file.Read(bytes, 0, bytes.Length);
string strresponse = Encoding.UTF8.GetString(bytes);

request.Method = "POST";
request.ContentType = "multipart/form-data;";
request.ContentLength = file.Length;

request.Headers.Add("hhrr", "H010");
request.Headers.Add("env", "TEST");
request.Headers.Add("buildLabel", "TNTAL_05.05.0500_C54");

Stream Postdata = request.GetRequestStream();
Postdata.Write(bytes, 0, bytes.Length);
HttpWebResponse response = (HttpWebResponse)request.GetResponse();`
```

`request.Headers.Add()` is adding parameters to URL? If not, how can I send multiple parameters to POST method in restful services?

Also, how to read parameters from file and make use in POST method?

Answer (score 1):

It needs a little leg work, encode a dictionary and put it in the body. Below is a quick sample:

```
private string Send(string url)
{
        HttpWebRequest request = WebRequest.Create(url) as HttpWebRequest;

        request.Method = "POST";

        string postData = EncodeDictionary(args, false);

        ASCIIEncoding encoding = new ASCIIEncoding();
        byte[] postDataBytes = encoding.GetBytes(postData);

        request.ContentType = "application/x-www-form-urlencoded";
        request.ContentLength = postDataBytes.Length;

        using(Stream requestStream = request.GetRequestStream())
        {
           requestStream.Write(postDataBytes, 0, postDataBytes.Length);
        }

        using (HttpWebResponse response = request.GetResponse() as HttpWebResponse)
        {
            StreamReader reader = new StreamReader(response.GetResponseStream());
            return reader.ReadToEnd();
        }
 }

private string EncodeDictionary(Dictionary<string, string> dict,
                                bool questionMark)
{
    StringBuilder sb = new StringBuilder();
    if (questionMark)
    {
        sb.Append("?");
    }
    foreach (KeyValuePair<string, string> kvp in dict)
    {
        sb.Append(HttpUtility.UrlEncode(kvp.Key));
        sb.Append("=");
        sb.Append(HttpUtility.UrlEncode(kvp.Value));
        sb.Append("&");
    }
    sb.Remove(sb.Length - 1, 1); // Remove trailing &
    return sb.ToString();
}
```

Answer (score 0):

I don't know what your complete requirements are, but my strong suggestion is to "start simple".

Do *not* use  "Content-type: multipart/form-data" unless you're sure you need it.  Instead, start out with "application/x-www-form-urlencoded" (an old favorite) or "application/json" (even better).

Here is a nice little step-by-step example.  You can find literally 100's more with a simple Google search:

- http://www.asp.net/web-api/overview/web-api-clients/calling-a-web-api-from-a-net-client